# Creating Multiple Vectors From a String Vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector, which stores a set of stings:

```r
v <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

I need to turn these strings into vectors.  Is there a way to do this where each element automatically becomes its own vector without creating each vector individually?

So that a, b, c are now vectors in the same dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to create separate variables? Why do you think that's necessary? What's the desired result here? What are you trying to do? Almost everything in R is a vector.

Comment: something like this `lzt <- split(v, c(1:length(v)))` ?